# How to derive Evidence Lower Bound in the paper "Zero-Shot Text-to-Image Generation"?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, probability, expectation-maximization, gpt

Can someone share the derivation of Evidence Lower Bound in this paper ?
[Zero-Shot Text-to-Image Generation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12092.pdf)

The overall procedure can be viewed as maximizing the
evidence lower bound (ELB) (Kingma & Welling, 2013;
Rezende et al., 2014) on the joint likelihood of the model
distribution over images x, captions y, and the tokens z
for the encoded RGB image. We model this distribution
using the factorization ${p_\theta,_\psi(x, y, z) = p_\theta(x | y, z)p_\psi(y, z)}$,
which yields the lower bound:
${\ln p_\theta,_\psi(x, y) > E_{z∼q_\phi(z | x)}\ln p_\theta(x | y, z) − \beta D_{KL}(q_\phi(y, z | x), p_\psi(y, z))}$